# Is there a way to disable this "often used with" prompt on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

Sometime within last 6 months my iPhone started showing a prompt on the bottom for apps that I don't have running in the background. I use the task switcher to close apps after I am done with, say, ordering food or what-now. And for most apps, like Audible mentioned in the prompt in below image, the "background app refresh" is turned off.

It looks as shown below.

[image: iPhone "Often used with Bluetooth" prompt]

**Some additional details:**
My iPhone 7 is running iOS v14.6. I may have had my iPhone connected to an Apple Watch at the time this message popped up. My internet search so far had found [these instructions here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7506608) (to disable it in Settings -> iTunes & App Store -> turn off suggested apps for installed apps) but the instructions do not seem to be valid for v14.6.

So with this background, would anyone know if there is a way to disable this "Often used with Bluetooth device connected" prompt?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you turn off “Siri Suggestions” you will not see those.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/about-siri-suggestions-iph6f94af287/ios

Option in on app usage patterns lets the “neural engine” process app history and look for patterns to suggest. I also find if you dismiss these, Siri sometimes takes the hint and stops suggesting things if you never tap in to use a class of recommendations.

I’ve also found it handy to leave these enabled but “bench” a few specific apps I never want suggested, indexed or searched.